# My Ubuntu 12.10 does not show the wireless network list

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

I tried everything I found on this site, all the related questions, but nothing seems to work. I am using a MacBook Pro, the 2012 release. I already tried installing fwcutter, and many other options, but the list of wireless network simply doesn't appear. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Simply uncheck Eneble Wi-fi (in the network menu by the volume control) and check it again. It worked for me with similar issue.